# error in using some malicious node in a scenario in ns2

Tags: ns2

I use an instruction to add some malicious node to my scenario the malicious node work in AODV.

Now by running this scenario I have this error:

```
me@HP-PC ~/Desktop/ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/tcl/ex $ ns smm.tcl
num_nodes is set 40
INITIALIZE THE LIST xListHead
ns: _o61 malicious :
(_o61 cmd line 1)
invoked from within
"_o61 cmd malicious"
invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
(procedure "_o61" line 2)
(SplitObject unknown line 2)
invoked from within
"_o61 malicious "
```

I attach the instruction and my scenaro here http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=5280563#post5280563

Answer (score 0):

**splitObject** error is a spacing error. I guess, you did a spacing error where you have mentioned "malicious". check it in both **tcl file and aodv.cc file**.

Answer (score 0):

Generally about "malicious aodv" : The ns-2.35 patch is aodv-malicious_ns235.patch https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNU0VNbUtIWlJpRk0/view?usp=sharing

The examples : aodv-malicious-examples-04.2015.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNbWw1Q21HWGhnSGc/view?usp=sharing

A Build example, post #2 here http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/i-tried-to-add-malicious-node-in-aodv-4175539353/#2

-

Answer (score -1):

It is exactly spaceing before "malicious".